# PDO Informix ODBC Driver work with PHP CLI but not in browser

Tags: php, linux, pdo, odbc, informix

I just try to create a connection to a database using the Informix Driver.

The server is running on CentOS 6.4, with PDO_INFORMIX-1.3.1 and clientsdk.4.10.FC2DE.LINUX.

I set env var in /etc/sysconfig/httpd, and run this command :

- chcon -t lib_t /opt/informix/lib/cli/*.so
- chcon -t lib_t /opt/informix/lib/*.so
- chcon -t lib_t/opt/informix/lib/esql/*.so
- chcon -t lib_t /opt/informix/lib/c++/*.so
- chcon -t lib_t /opt/informix/lib/dim/*.so
- chcon -t lib_t /opt/informix/lib/client/cms/*.so
- chcon -t lib_t /opt/informix/OAT/Apache_2.4.2/modules/*.so
- chcon -t lib_t /opt/informix/OAT/PHP_5.4.4/*.so
- chcon -t lib_t /opt/informix/OAT/PHP_5.4.4/lib/php/extensions/*.so
- /sbin/ldconfig
- setenforce 0

When i run "php /var/www/html/informix.php" the connection is succesful, but when i call the same script on a browser, i get this error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE=08004, SQLDriverConnect: -908 [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]Attempt to connect to database server (cms_net) failed.' in /var/www/html/informix.php:30 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/informix.php(30): PDO->__construct('informix:host=1...', 'user', 'xxxxx') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/informix.php on line 30
```

I try to set a host in /etc/hosts, no success.

I don't know what to do to solve this problem. Anyone can help me ?

Comment: if it's selinux, there'll be log traces to say WHY the connection was denied.

Comment: did you restarted apache after set the environments at sysconfig? did you check with phpinfo if the variables was really defined at apache scope?

Comment: I forgot comment before, if you check the access/errorlog of apache I'm pretty sure you will found the error message with more details there.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. I solve the problem. Indeed, SELinux was the cause. I just do "setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve the problem. Indeed, SELinux was the cause. I just do

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
```

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes SElinux is a nightmare!